# mlr - How to see the direction (positive or negative) features influencing the target variable

Tags: r, feature-selection, mlr

Let's start with an simple linear regression output ([copied from here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59250/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-the-summary-method-for-an-lm-object-in-r)),

```
Call:
lm(formula = a1 ~ ., data = clean.algae[, 1:12])

Residuals:
  Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
  -37.679 -11.893  -2.567   7.410  62.190 

  Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
  (Intercept)  42.942055  24.010879   1.788  0.07537 . 
  seasonspring  3.726978   4.137741   0.901  0.36892   
  seasonsummer  0.747597   4.020711   0.186  0.85270   
  seasonwinter  3.692955   3.865391   0.955  0.34065   
  sizemedium    3.263728   3.802051   0.858  0.39179   
  sizesmall     9.682140   4.179971   2.316  0.02166 * 
  speedlow      3.922084   4.706315   0.833  0.40573   
  speedmedium   0.246764   3.241874   0.076  0.93941   
  mxPH         -3.589118   2.703528  -1.328  0.18598   
  mnO2          1.052636   0.705018   1.493  0.13715   
  Cl           -0.040172   0.033661  -1.193  0.23426   
  NO3          -1.511235   0.551339  -2.741  0.00674 **
  NH4           0.001634   0.001003   1.628  0.10516   
  oPO4         -0.005435   0.039884  -0.136  0.89177   
  PO4          -0.052241   0.030755  -1.699  0.09109 . 
  Chla         -0.088022   0.079998  -1.100  0.27265   
  ---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

  Residual standard error: 17.65 on 182 degrees of freedom
  Multiple R-squared:  0.3731,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3215 
  F-statistic: 7.223 on 15 and 182 DF,  p-value: 2.444e-12
```

From this output we can see the model fitness as well as what are the variables are significantly affecting the target variable. Also, we can see by looking at the sign of the coefficients whether the variable is affecting negatively or positively.

Now look at this example [from the `mlr` package manual](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr/articles/feature_selection.html),

```
### Select features
sfeats = selectFeatures(learner = "surv.coxph", task = wpbc.task, resampling = rdesc,
  control = ctrl, show.info = FALSE)
sfeats
## FeatSel result:
## Features (14): mean_radius, mean_compactness, mean_concavepoints, mean_symmetry, mean_fractaldim, SE_perimeter, SE_area, SE_concavity, SE_fractaldim, worst_radius, worst_perimeter, worst_concavity, worst_concavepoints, tsize
## cindex.test.mean=0.6718346
```

From the above output I can see the list of features that are important. My question is, how can I see the direction (positive or negative) features (independent variables) are affecting the target variable? Anyone here to help on this issue? Recommended reading materials would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Addition**

I am trying to implement your suggestion in the example multilabel classification [`yeast.task` example](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr/articles/multilabel.html),

```
library(mlr)
library(mmpf)

yeast <-  getTaskData(yeast.task)
labels <- colnames(yeast)[1:14]
yeast.task <- makeMultilabelTask(id = "multi", data = yeast, target = labels)

lrn.br <- makeLearner("classif.rpart", predict.type = "prob")
lrn.br <- makeMultilabelBinaryRelevanceWrapper(lrn.br)

mod <- mlr::train(lrn.br, yeast.task, subset = 1:1500, weights = rep(1/1500, 1500))
pred <- predict(mod, newdata = yeast[1501:1600,])

performance(pred, measures = list(multilabel.subset01, multilabel.hamloss, multilabel.acc,
                                   multilabel.f1, timepredict))

rdesc <- makeResampleDesc(method = "CV", stratify = FALSE, iters = 3)
r <- resample(learner = lrn.br, task = yeast.task, resampling = rdesc, show.info = FALSE)

getMultilabelBinaryPerformances(pred, measures = list(acc, mmce, auc))
getMultilabelBinaryPerformances(r$pred, measures = list(acc, mmce))

getLearnerModel(mod)

pd <- generatePartialDependenceData(mod, yeast.task)
plotPartialDependence(pd)
```

The last three 3 lines giving me the following output. I am not sure if these are anything useful. Any idea if I am doing something wrong?

```
> getLearnerModel(mod)
$label1
Model for learner.id=classif.rpart; learner.class=classif.rpart
Trained on: task.id = label1; obs = 1500; features = 103
Hyperparameters: xval=0

$label2
Model for learner.id=classif.rpart; learner.class=classif.rpart
Trained on: task.id = label2; obs = 1500; features = 103
Hyperparameters: xval=0

$label3
Model for learner.id=classif.rpart; learner.class=classif.rpart
Trained on: task.id = label3; obs = 1500; features = 103
Hyperparameters: xval=0

$label4
Model for learner.id=classif.rpart; learner.class=classif.rpart
Trained on: task.id = label4; obs = 1500; features = 103
Hyperparameters: xval=0

$label5
Model for learner.id=classif.rpart; learner.class=classif.rpart
Trained on: task.id = label5; obs = 1500; features = 103
Hyperparameters: xval=0

$label6
Model for learner.id=classif.rpart; learner.class=classif.rpart
Trained on: task.id = label6; obs = 1500; features = 103
Hyperparameters: xval=0

$label7
Model for learner.id=classif.rpart; learner.class=classif.rpart
Trained on: task.id = label7; obs = 1500; features = 103
Hyperparameters: xval=0

$label8
Model for learner.id=classif.rpart; learner.class=classif.rpart
Trained on: task.id = label8; obs = 1500; features = 103
Hyperparameters: xval=0

$label9
Model for learner.id=classif.rpart; learner.class=classif.rpart
Trained on: task.id = label9; obs = 1500; features = 103
Hyperparameters: xval=0

$label10
Model for learner.id=classif.rpart; learner.class=classif.rpart
Trained on: task.id = label10; obs = 1500; features = 103
Hyperparameters: xval=0

$label11
Model for learner.id=classif.rpart; learner.class=classif.rpart
Trained on: task.id = label11; obs = 1500; features = 103
Hyperparameters: xval=0

$label12
Model for learner.id=classif.rpart; learner.class=classif.rpart
Trained on: task.id = label12; obs = 1500; features = 103
Hyperparameters: xval=0

$label13
Model for learner.id=classif.rpart; learner.class=classif.rpart
Trained on: task.id = label13; obs = 1500; features = 103
Hyperparameters: xval=0

$label14
Model for learner.id=classif.rpart; learner.class=classif.rpart
Trained on: task.id = label14; obs = 1500; features = 103
Hyperparameters: xval=0

> 
> pd <- generatePartialDependenceData(mod, yeast.task)
Error in data.table(preds, design[, vars, drop = FALSE], key = vars) : 
  column or argument 1 is NULL
> plotPartialDependence(pd)
Error in checkClass(x, classes, ordered, null.ok) : object 'pd' not found
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract the coefficients of the underlaying learner model you have to use `getLearnerModel()` in mlr:

```
library(mlr)
mod = train(learner = "surv.coxph", task = lung.task)
getLearnerModel(mod)
```

Output:

```
Call:
survival::coxph(formula = f, data = data)

               coef exp(coef)  se(coef)     z       p
inst      -3.04e-02  9.70e-01  1.31e-02 -2.31 0.02062
age        1.28e-02  1.01e+00  1.19e-02  1.07 0.28340
sex       -5.67e-01  5.67e-01  2.01e-01 -2.81 0.00489
ph.ecog    9.07e-01  2.48e+00  2.39e-01  3.80 0.00014
ph.karno   2.66e-02  1.03e+00  1.16e-02  2.29 0.02223
pat.karno -1.09e-02  9.89e-01  8.14e-03 -1.34 0.18016
meal.cal   2.60e-06  1.00e+00  2.68e-04  0.01 0.99224
wt.loss   -1.67e-02  9.83e-01  7.91e-03 -2.11 0.03465

Likelihood ratio test=33.7  on 8 df, p=5e-05
n= 167, number of events= 120
```

If you are interested in interpetability that is independent from the *learner* then you can have a look at partial dependence plots. For `coxph` they are not suprisingly linear:

```
pd = generatePartialDependenceData(mod, lung.task)
plotPartialDependence(pd)
```

[image: coxph_partial_dependence]

But you could also use a random forest for survival data:

```
mod2 = train(learner = "surv.randomForestSRC", task = lung.task)
pd2 = generatePartialDependenceData(mod2, lung.task)
plotPartialDependence(pd2)
```

[image: random_forest_partial_dependence]

However, partial dependence plots also have to be interpreted with care. So you should read about it e.g. [here](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/pdp.html).
Also you can have a look at ICE plots.

Comment: Thank a lot. I am looking something like this I guess. I have added one multi-label classification example in the original question. I am getting the output like this (also added in the original quesion), 

`> pd <- generatePartialDependenceData(mod, yeast.task)
Error in data.table(preds, design[, vars, drop = FALSE], key = vars) : 
  column or argument 1 is NULL
> plotPartialDependence(pd)
Error in checkClass(x, classes, ordered, null.ok) : object 'pd' not found `
Is it possible that your solution is not applicable to multilabel case?

Answer (score 0):

You can get more information on what was happening during the feature selection using the `$opt.path` member of the result, but in general it doesn't make sense to give positive and negative correlations/effects for a single feature. For most models, you can't define a directional correlation as for linear regression because it doesn't make sense for the particular model. The feature selection function is model-agnostic.

Even evaluating whether a particular feature increases the performance of the model (positive effect) or decreases it (negative effect) doesn't make sense for this type of selection as it takes feature interactions into account. For a particular feature you might get a positive effect for a particular subset of the other features and a negative effect for another.

Finally, correlating features with the output isn't just dependent on the model, but also on the features -- it only works for numeric features.